# Why my API's JSON Response is not displaying in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, api

I need to display the JSON response received from an API call. But due to some issues it doesn't display the response. Server/IP settings, API status are everything OK at API provider's end. So now, I couldn't figure out the issue.

I'm doing the PHP part in the following way:

**PHP**

```
$url="https://api.domain.com/getdata.php?format=json&token=2455445444&type=ROWS";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    
    $json = json_decode($output, true);

    $resCode = $json['resCode'];
    $resText = $json['resText'];

    $rows = $json['data']['ROWS'];


    if (count($rows) > 0) {

                        echo "<table border='1' width='50%' align='center'><thead><tr>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Detail</th>
                        <th>Validity (days)</th>
                        <th>Talktime</th>
                        </tr></thead><tbody>";
                        foreach($rows as $key => $value)
                        {
                            echo " <tr><td>" .$value["column1"] . "</td> <td>" .$value["column2"] . "</td> <td>" .$value["column3"] . "</td> <td>" .$value["column4"] . "</td> </tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</tbody></table><br/>";
                }
                echo "Not available <br/> Try again!";
```

**JSON Response from API**

```
{
    "data":{

        "ROWS": [
                    {
                        "column1":"123",
                        "column2":"456",
                        "column3":"789",
                        "column4":"054"
                    },
                    {
                        "column1":"775",
                        "column2":"545",
                        "column3":"647",
                        "column4":"745"
                    },
                    {
                        "column1":"440",
                        "column2":"544",
                        "column3":"745",
                        "column4":"999"
                    }
                ]
        },

    "resCode":"200",
    "resText":"SUCCESS"

}
```

**Getting Output:**

```
Not available  
Try again!
```

**Expecting Output in HTML**

```
<table border="1" width="50%" align="center">
<thread>
<tr>
  <th>Column 1</th>
  <th>Column 2</th>
  <th>Column 3</th>
  <th>Column 4</th>
</tr>
</thread>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>456</td>
  <td>789</td>
  <td>054</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>775</td>
  <td>545</td>
  <td>647</td>
  <td>745</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>440</td>
  <td>544</td>
  <td>745</td>
  <td>999</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `$rows = $json['data']['RMG'];`? What is RMG? Is it possible that this should be ROWS instead?

Comment: @kyeiti Sorry it was a spelling mistake.. Still not working

Comment: @CodeGodie It's showing complete blank page

Comment: then youre not getting the results you think you have.

Comment: @CodeGodie But when I directly copy and open the API url in browser, it responses properly.

Comment: doesnt work for me. Is that open to the public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `curl_error($ch)` to know if there's any error with curl. And it let me know that I'm facing the issue because of SSL validation issue with the API URL.

So, I removed the `s` from `https` in the API URL. And it worked!

I know its a security compromise! But the referrer url is using http, so I need to remove the SSL validation from api url too.